# TimePicker widget not getting current time

Tags: android, keyboard, timepicker

This question is about TimePicker behavior in Android.

To get the value of the Hour and the Minute I use getCurrentHour() and getCurrentMinute().

At first I found out that changes made by the user using the phone keyboard where not registered so calling getCurrentHour() or getCurrentMinute() did not show the values changed in the texboxes inside the widget.
This was quickly solved using setAddStatesFromChildren(true); With this I get those changes.

Now, my problem is that those changes are only registered if timepicker looses focus.
So, getting the value from timepicker inside a button gets a wrong value because it hasn't loose focus.
Any help?

What I need is: Can I force a timepicker to loose focus and get the real written value in text boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it and I write it here for someone who needs it.
Thanks to "Tarun Maheshwari" I found what I needed:

On onCreate do something like this:

```
MyTimerPicker.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
```

On the onClick method, when getting the values, do this:

```
MyTimerPicker.clearFocus();
int iHour = MyTimerPicker.getCurrentHour();
int iMinute = MyTimerPicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call clearFocus() on the timepicker view after you get onTimeChanged callback.